# Why can't a classical bit behave like a qubit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space, quantum-computer, superposition

For example i have a 2 qubits which can have 4 possibilities i.e. 00, 01, 10, 11 so this shows that the 2 qubits can contain four bits of information as they are superpositioned but i think 2 classical computer bits can also have 4 possibilities 00, 01, 10 ,11 then whats the difference between qubits and bits?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition).

Let's take one classical bit. It can be in two states: $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$.

Now let's consider a qubit: its general state will be

$$a |0\rangle + b |1\rangle$$

where $a,b$ are complex numbers with the constraint

$$|a|^2+|b|^2=1$$

Now you should be able to see the difference. A state like

$$\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$

is impossible for a classical bit (it just doesn't make any sense: a classical bit is either $0$ *or* $1$). A quantum bit, on the other hand, can be something "between" $0$ and $1$, but different from either one.

Notice that the number of states in the form $a |0\rangle + b |1\rangle$ with $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$ is *infinite*. As a matter of fact, they can be mapped on the surface of the unitary sphere (the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit#Bloch_sphere)), which is a continuum of points.

Answer (score 2):

Bits are just like ordinary qubits, except that they are always entangled with the environment. Each bit has two preferred basis states, |0> and |1>. If somehow you create a superposition between these two states, the bit and the environment will evolve into a  state of the form |A>|0> + |B>|1> where |A> and |B> describe the rest of the universe, these states are almost orthogonal after a very short time. This is called decoherence and it prevents you from using ordinary bits to do quantum computations.

Comment: How is a quantum bit entangled?

Comment: Ideal qubits will not get entangled (except with other qubits if the quantum algorithm that is applied makes that happen). In practice, interactions with the environment will cause entanglement between the qubits and the environmental degrees of freedom. Classical bits of an ordinary computer are not made with any intentions to be able to do quantum computing, but in principle you may consider that. This then leads to the conclusion that they are in fact qubits, but they decohere so fast that it's not possible to run any quantum algorithm at all.

Answer (score 1):

For the qubits, you have the states that you listed above, but you can also form any superposition of these states. For example the state
$\frac{01+e^{i\theta}10}{\sqrt{2}}$ is a valid qubit for any real number $\theta$.

The two qubits thus contain more information than their classical counterparts.

Comment: Your last claim is pretty iffy - you can indeed encode more than one bit of information in a one-qubit state, but you'd need a large amount of copies of the state to actually decode that information. The asymptotic amount of information you can encode in a string of qubits is only one bit per qubit, so the difference is somewhat more subtle than just "qubits contain more information".

Comment: @Emilio, that isn't quite true. Look up superdense coding.

Comment: ... in which protocol two qubits are involved. If Alice and Bob have had no previous contact, and Alice wants to put information in a box and send it to Bob, she needs to send both. Superdense coding allows her, in a sense, to 'pre-send' one of the qubits, before she actually encodes the information, but nothing more.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yes, I agree. The difference between bits and qubits is indeed more involved than the fact that qubits have a larger capacity to store information (which they do). To be clear, this was only meant as an answer to "aren't they the same thing?" Since qubits and bits are apples and oranges in some sense, listing all of the differences in a complete way may not be practical or instructive.

Comment: @Orko how does a qubit have a larger capacity to store information than a bit, both have 2 possibilities 0, 1?

Comment: @Bhavesh As pointed out, the answer is a little subtle. You might try to encode $A = 0$, $B = 1$, $C = (0+i1)/\sqrt{2}$. But if you measure in the (0,1) basis say, you need more than 1 measurement to determine the state (in any basis, you'll get a 0 or 1.) However with a more involved setup, such as superdense coding, you can win. (to be continued ...)

Comment: @Bhavesh  (... continued) Essentially the idea is that two parties share an entangled qubit and measure in a special basis. This allows for 2 bits of information per qubit. Note though that people tend to argue as to whether superdense coding truly sends more information because it assumes an initial transfer of information.

Comment: @Bhavesh (cont ...) Information capacity aside, there are many other differences between bits and qubits. For example: mathematically they live in different spaces and physically, their value can be time dependant and depend on basis choice. See for example [these notes].(https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/quantum/talksarchive/clap3/clap3-bobcoecke.pdf).

Answer (score -2):

Lets not use technical terms and understand this bit by bit, by example.

In classical terms if a cat is kept with a radioactive poison inside a box, without any type of knowledge of what is going inside. A person with common sense would say that the cat is either alive "OR" dead. The word OR here is emphasized, because of some reason which we will come to know now. However, a Quantum Physicist would say that the cat is dead "AND" alive at the same time. Note the difference between the statements OR-AND. (Note: Cat is just used as an example, technically cat is not a quantum object, it has a greater rest mass and hence greater De Broglie wavelength).

Now, lets look at what a bit does. It stores information for calculation. So if a Qubit was used instead of bit, it can store two times more information than a single qubit. 2 qubits can store 4 times and N qubits can store 2^n times more information. If suitable Algorithms are used to exploit this idea, it can speed up computation exponentially.

You are missing the word "Simultaneously" in your understanding. You can have all the 00, 01, 10, 11 calculated at the same time using a Quantum Computer.

Comment: Atleast post a reason for downvoting.